# JPA two Entities one Relationship: How do I obtain a Set of an entity that is linked through a relationship?

Tags: jpa

I have three tables each mapping to one of these entities. The 'assigned' table acts as the relationship between 'users' and 'roles' with a foreign key to each table. How would I map this on my entities so that I can get a Set of EntityRoles from the UserEntity? I can't quite figure out how to make this work. Is this even possible?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="user_username")
    private String username;


    @Column(name="user_password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="user_email")
    private String email;

    //I want to be able to get a set of RoleEntities
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "assigned")
public class AssignedEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    //@Column(name = "assigned_role")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = RoleEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role")
    private long roleId;

    @Id
    //@Column(name = "assigned_user")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
    private long userId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="role_id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="roleId")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="role_name")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: you cant put relation annotations (e.g `@OneToOne`) on a non-relation field (e.g "long id"), as per any JPA docs tell you

Answer (score 1):

You are using an incorrect/inconvenient mapping. Always keep things as simply as possible.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

A persistent provider will create a (valid) join table for you. You can specify the name of the join table using `@JoinTable` annotation. Also you will need to think about auto generation values of `id` for the `Role` entity: the `roles` table is something like a reference data table. So, probably, you will need to hardcode the `id` values.

To get user roles (in the persistent context):

```
user.getRoles()
```